# Django Q lookup search in title for strings from a list returns duplicates

Tags: python, django, database, list, django-models

sorry if my question is weird or incoherent.

What I'm trying to do is this:

I take the string that the user has typed out as his search input and create a list of strings from that input, and then create a loop that goes over the list and searches for each item in that list in database, let me make it a bit clearer with some code:

```
#I take the string that the user inputs as his search

query = request.GET.get('q')

# I create a list by spliting the original search string
query_srch = query.split()

# Create a list which will later hold the items returned by the db lookup
searchnews = []

#start the loop to lookup
for word in query_srch:
    if word:
        searchnews += NewsPost.objects.filter(
            Q(title__icontains=word)
        ).distinct().order_by('-date')
```

The reason why I do this is because if the title of an article in your website is  "Obama: blablabla", but the user searches for "Barack Obama", the article "Obama: blablabla" will not actually come up at all.

The problem is that when I do this for loop search thing, if my search query is 
"Obama Obama Obama", I will get a list with each article not duplicated but triplicated (I think I made that word up).
If I search for "Obama Obama Obama Obama" I will get each article quatruplicated(the same article 4 times) etc etc.. I hope you get what I mean.

I worked around this for a while by just taking the end list which in my case is 
**searchnews** and using the inbuilt python function set(), like this:

```
searchnews = set(searchnews)
```

but this changes the order of the items in the list and I need them ordered by date.

Any chance you can help ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't send queries in a loop! Make one query that satisfies the requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to deal with this scenario.

**Method 1:**(We can avoid the for loop)

```
import operator
from django.db.models import Q

search_term = request.GET.get('q')

query = reduce(operator.and_, (Q(title__contains = item) for item in search_term.split()))

posts = NewsPost.objects.filter(query).distinct().order_by('-date')
```

**Method 2**

If you want to stick on your current code try to remove duplicates from query ie, `query_srch = list(set(query.split()))`, so that if you type "Obama Obama Obama" you only get one "Obama" in `query_srch`

Comment: Thanks, I`ll try the first approach (avoiding the loop).. As for the second approach, as I said, the function set() removes the order of the list so I cannot do with that .